# Feature 'ba4cc06d-b95a-4eb1-8898-88d940efa09b' for list template '106' is not installed in this farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am facing the issue in the SharePoint 2013 farm solution (In WebPart- while adding the n number of lists to datatable here:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"106\" />";
query.Query = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='Text'>" + _contentTypeId + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>"; 
query.RowLimit = (uint)Convert.ToInt32(ItemLimit);
DataTable results = new DataTable();
results = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

as below

> Feature 'ba4cc06d-b95a-4eb1-8898-88d940efa09b' for list template '106' is not installed in this farm.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is normally there when there is something wrong with the list schema. Possible causes you should check for:

1. Are there any lists on your web which are deployed using a feature, but the feature is missing/deactivated?
2. There might be list with a lookup column, and there is some issue with the lookup.

*Fortunately* I haven't had this error frequently enough to make out all the patterns. :)

Comment: As you mentioned in the comment - I have created the Calendar with default content type **Event**.
So here is no chance of list schema issue.
And here is no any feature remaining to activate.
Thanks!!!